# how to lineup css boxes?

Tags: css, html

I have been busting my butt, just to lineup my pics in css boxes
here is the code(and the screen shop of result) its in the blade(laravel5) :

---

[image]

---

Here is my code:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
        <div style="width: 200px;height: 200px;background-color: gray;text-align: center; float: right; margin-bottom: 22px;
                    margin-right: 17px;
         ">
            <a href="{{route('users.profile',$user->username)}}"><img src="{{$user->getavatar()}}" alt="{!!$user->username!!}" ></a>
            <strong>{!!$user->username!!}</strong>
        </div>
        <br>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @Radmation I see no evidence or mentions of Bootstrap.

Comment: Try setting a max width on your <img> for 100%. Try setting your anchor tag to display: block;  Wrap your <strong> with a <p> tag. Let me know results.

Comment: side note: You should try to avoid using inline styles. Also you should look into css frameworks (recommend bootstrap) - they will save you a lot of time in the future. Plus some employers like you to know them.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please including your CSS and the rendered HTML.

Comment: @Radmation thnak you for response . yes i am using bootstrap . as far as i know its loaded in laravel5.2 . but i'll do what you said . then i will tell you the result

Answer (score 1):

Let's try another method using `display` instead of using `float`, and remove the `<br>`. How does this look?

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; text-align: center; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 0 10px 22px;">
    <a href="{{route('users.profile',$user->username)}}"><img src="{{$user->getavatar()}}" alt="{!!$user->username!!}" ></a>
    <strong>{!!$user->username!!}</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4573410/jon-uleis i got it , was cuz of <br>

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your `foreach loop divs` inside a `div` container and use `display:flex`. It is better not to use css inline with yout html code(It looks heavy), also `<br>` is not needed there.
Please review this one:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 50px;
}
#container div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;   /*or using calc(100% / 6);*/
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 0;  
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  margin-right: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!--sample result of your foreach loop-->
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <!--end foreach-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br>` tag at the end of the `foreach`  loop.